# PHP CodeIgniter: Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've loaded the libraries necessary in the controller, but still faced this problem. Please check out my codes, thank you. Putting into autoload also doesn't work.

This is my Controller: studCred

```
class studCred extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('form_validation');    
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('studCredModeller');
}
    //Register students
    public function create() {

    //load registration view form
    $this->load->view('studCred/Create');



    //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_check_username_exists');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('adminNo', 'AdminNo', 'required|callback_check_adminNo_exists');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_check_email_exists');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone',  'required');

         if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
             $this->load->view('studCred/Create');
         }
         else 
         {
             $this->studCredModeller->saveRecords();
             $this->load->view('nypportal');


        }
    }
}
```

This is my Modeller: studCredModeller

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit ('No direct script access allowed!');

class studCredModeller extends CI_Model
{
    public function saveRecords()
    {

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data = array(
        'username' =>$this->input->post('username'),
        'admin_no' =>$this->input->post('adminNo'),
        'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'));



}
return $this->db->insert('stud_login', $data);
}
?>
```

This is my View: Create

```
<?php echo form_open('studCred/Create'); ?>
                 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Username</label>   
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                       <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Admin No</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adminNo" placeholder="AdminNo">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Phone number</label>
                           <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">

                        </div>
                      </div>
                       </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="save" class="btn btn-skin btn-block btn-lg">

                    <p class="lead-footer">* We'll contact you by phone & email later</p>


                  </form>
```

Thanks for checking out the codes! Still quite new to PHP this whole thing.

Comment: dear if u still have problem with form helper pls install a fresh ci project and check whether it is working for u or not , just to check

Comment: did you try `form_open_multipart()` too?

Comment: try with `<form action="studCred/Create" method="post">` insted of `<?php echo form_open('studCred/Create'); ?>`

Comment: @YadhuBabu thank you! But now I faced undefined validation_errors, is there another way to define it?

Comment: @Bob autoload `form_validation` in autoload.php or use `$this->load->library('form_validation');` inside `create` function

Comment: Have you loaded the form helper?